# Overload variadic function for a single specific type using C++17

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20, variadic-templates

I want to overload (or specialize) a variadic function, such that the overload (or specialization) takes only arguments of a specific type. In C++20 I would write:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

// original version
void foo(auto const&...) { std::cout << "default\n"; }

// oveload/specialization takes only Bar instances
struct Bar {};
void foo(std::same_as<Bar> auto const&...){ std::cout << "Bar\n"; }
```

The code works as expected. The second version is chosen, if the arguments are all `Bar`, the first otherwise. How would I create the second overload with C++17? Ideally, I wouldn't have to modify the more general version.

Here is a first failed attempt using `std::enable_if`: https://godbolt.org/z/9vn39jTd4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have "typo" in your attempt:

`std::enable_if_t<(std::is_same_v<Bar, Ts> && ...), /* void */> = nullptr` is wrong.

`std::enable_if_t<(std::is_same_v<Bar, Ts> && ...), std::nullptr_t> = nullptr` would fix the typo.

Unfortunately, it is insufficient.
C++20 has subsumption to have more "specialized" overload.

With C++17, neither of

- `template <typename... Ts> void bar(Ts const& ...)`
- `template <typename... Ts, std::enable_if_t<(std::is_same_v<Bar, Ts> && ...), std::nullptr_t> = nullptr> void bar(Ts const& ...)`

is more specialized.

Fortunately, you can have:

```
template <typename... Ts,
    std::enable_if_t<(std::is_same_v<Bar, Ts> && ...), std::nullptr_t> = nullptr
>
void bar(const Bar&, Ts const& ...){ std::cout << "Bar\n"; }
```

which is a better match.

Moreover, add overload for empty pack `void bar()` if you consider no arguments as `Bar`.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/r86GfbPYz)

Note:
as `{}` as no type, it can't be deduced, but as **first** argument of `bar` IS a `Bar`, `bar({})` would works (whereas `foo({})` won't).

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't compile on MSVC. I modified your code to use `std::enable_if_t` in the return value and it compiles on MSVC >19.20 and provokes an internal compiler error for earlier versions: https://godbolt.org/z/h95r7rxn4.

Comment: MSVC seems to have issue with the folding expression, there is a trick `(std::is_same_v<Bar, Ts> && ...)` <=> `std::is_same_v<type_list<Bar, Ts...>, type_list<Ts..., Bar>)`  [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EnTGsrq8h) (I use `std::tuple` as `type_list`).